# What does "To book in house" mean?

Tags: hotels, bookings, terminology

[A conference](http://congress.cmos.ca/site/services/accommodations) advertises special rates for conference guests in local hotels.  On the website, they write:

> To book in house, email  guestservices@panpacific.com  or Phone 604-905-2999 or Toll Free 1-888-905-9995. Group Affiliation:  CMOS

What does *in house* mean in this context?

Comment: My guess without context: It's a contact to a booking agency who will make the arrangements for you using the discounts that the conference has arranged.

Comment: I've edited the question to add more context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't, so far as I can tell, any kind of travel jargon. It looks the standard definition of *[in-house](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/in-house)* used in any kind of business:

> Done or existing within an organization

That is, if you want to book a room directly through the hotel itself, use the contact information provided. Presumably, you could also book the room through a third party like a consolidator, online travel agency, or corporate portal— which might or might not be cheaper and/or easier.